# Error getting while building react kotlin app using IntelliJ

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-js, create-react-kotlin-app

I've created a simple react app using `create-react-kotlin-app`. After successful `npm start`, I tried to get a build of the project using `IntelliJ IDEA`'s `Build -> Build Project`, but it fails stating

> Error:(16, 44) Kotlin: Can't access property 'reactLogo' marked with @JsModule annotation from non-modular project

What am I missing here ?

NOTE: I haven't done any modification in the template comes with `create-react-kotlin-app`. The project runs successfully, problem only exist when I try to get a build.

Comment: You can enable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | *Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle* to make IDE use Gradle build instead of IDE own builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got managed to fix this issue via `terminal`.

From the project root, run

```
react-scripts-kotlin build
```

This will automatically creates a `build` folder with production ready files.